# Configuring Terminal to accept [<Control>-<Return>]

Tags: macos, keyboard, terminal

I'm using org-mode in emacs on MacOS X Lion (10.7). One of the commands to use is  (i.e. the control key, chorded with the return key). When I press this nothing happens. Doing some further investigation, I found that emacs is just receiving the return NOT the ctrl modifier key along with it. I know this because I did a C-q (i.e. control-letter 'q') and then tried to do a C-RETURN, with just the RETURN showing up.

I used the keyboard viewer to confirm that I am really pressing C-RETURN. Is there a way to configure Terminal.app (or my system) to send/accept C-Return?

Answer (score 0):

Terminal's keyboard map preference won't let you map the Return key. However, you can map one of the supported keys to send the input sequence that you expect Control-Return to send.

You want to send the sequence:

```
ESC [ 2 7 ; 5 ; 1 3 ~
```

(In Terminal preferences, when you type ESC it is displayed numerically as "\003".)

That's what emacs displays for `<C-return>` if you enter `M-x describe-bindings`.

Note that in Emacs 22.1.1 (the version installed with 10.8.3) org-mode has a mapping for Meta-Return, but not Control-Return. Are you sure you didn't mean Meta?